# Yet Another "Cannot Find Symbol Variable DaggerAppComponent"

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm finally stepping into Dagger (2) and created the minimal possible addition to my project by:

**CurrencyServiceModule:**

```
@Module
public class CurrencyServiceModule {

    @Provides
    @NonNull
    @Singleton
    public CurrencyService provideCurrencyService(){
        return new CurrencyService();
    }
}
```

**AppComponent.java:**

```
@Component(modules = {CurrencyServiceModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(ChargeDetailsFragment fragment);
}
```

And initialization:

```
public class AgentApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        component = buildComponent();
    }

    private AppComponent buildComponent(){
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .currencyServiceModule(new CurrencyServiceModule())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Still the DaggerAppComponent is not generated!

Already tried general advice for this compile error with no results. I assume it may depend on my annotations definition, so basically Dagger does not build the required code. Is there any way to see the Dagger log to understand what's happening?

Update: Gradle config:

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
```

Comment: When you build the project, what is the error, post it please

Comment: /works/control-android/control/src/main/java/co/getcontrol/ControlApplication.java
Error:(475, 16) error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerAppComponent
Error:Execution failed for task ':control:compileAggregateIntegrationJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Either remove this line and compile again, or look before this error, if Dagger is not able to generate the component, it's because somehow it cannot satisfy the dependencies you need, it will tell where the problem is

Comment: also make sure you added dagger's compiler to the annotation processing. This might be a reason why classes are not generated.

Comment: @Fred . how to check it? in gradle? 

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'

Comment: @elmorabea  how do I find in gradle build log why Dagger failed? I tried but could not identify where exactly to look